# Set state on field change

Tags: javascript, react.js

I have a contact model, on change I set the state of the `contact` object, how can I make the below function more readable?

The `address` field is different because it's an object: `['address', 'city', 'state', 'zip']`

```
  const onFieldChange = (
    key,
    index = 0,
    isMulti = false,
    isAddress = false
  ) => event => {
    const value = event.target.value
    const updatedContact = {...contact}
    if (!isMulti) {
      updatedContact[key] = value
      if (
        key === 'type' &&
        value === 'Individual' &&
        contact.entityFormationDate
      ) {
        delete updatedContact.entityFormationDate
      }
    } else {
      const keyInternal = isAddress ? key : 'value'
      key = isAddress ? 'addresses' : key
      updatedContact[key][index][keyInternal] = value
    }
    setContact(updatedContact)
  }
```

Comment: I don't see anything that can be improved in your code. In particular I don't see any repetition or any other boring code. Splitting the code into several smaller functions would not help either since that would mean way more code to read. So I guess it's already perfect.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: @TobySpeight Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do :

```
  const onFieldChange = (
    key,
    index = 0,
    isMulti = false,
    isAddress = false
  ) => event => {
    const value = event.target.value
    const updatedContact = {...contact}
    if (!isMulti) {
      updatedContact[key] = value
    }
    if (!isMulti && // see this
        key === 'type' &&
        value === 'Individual' &&
        contact.entityFormationDate
      ) {
        delete updatedContact.entityFormationDate
      }
    if (isMulti) {
      const keyInternal = isAddress ? key : 'value'
      key = isAddress ? 'addresses' : key
      updatedContact[key][index][keyInternal] = value
    }
    setContact(updatedContact)
  }
```

That way you lose a level of nestedness, and it doesn't really change any of the logic

Comment: If you can do the check of `key=='type' && value ...` before the `updatedContact`, then you can switch those two statements and create an if/else, rather than `if(!isMulti)` and an `if(isMulti)` but tbh, this is still okay.

Comment: The body of the second `if` statement is indented too far to the right.

Answer (score 2):

Code readability is a subjective quantity, however it is still considered as on-topic here at Code-Review.

### General readability points

Note that code in isolation is must rely on presumptions. The scope, naming, and missing defines may force some of the following points to change if known.

- Use simplest statements possible. For example the statement `if (!isMulti) {` can be simplified to `if (isMulti) {` and swapping the code blocks.
- Avoid breaking lines unless they extend past the right of screen.

  Some people use 80 columns (a little last century in my book (word warp is standard in IDE's these days)), 120 or even 160 will be readable in all but the smallest of devices.
- Avoid repetition. You test `isAddress` twice within the listener. This can be done once outside the returned function. See rewrite.

  This may not be considered a readability issue, but part of good code readability is clearly showing intent.

  To read the two lines testing `isAddress` I immediately questioned why in the event? This is already known? I had to check as your intent was muddied.
- The function `onFieldChange` is not an event listener, it returns a listener. The the prefixed `on` obfuscates its usage.

  The name would be better as just `createFieldChangeEvent`, `fieldChangeListener`, or `fieldChange` depending on the functions scope.
- Semicolons go a long way to improve readability, especially for coders that are swapping between C like languages.
- The string literals should be constants, however without the full scope and usage of these strings it is hard to define where and how to declare. So I leave them as is (apart from changing to double quotes)

### Rewrite

Two rewrites to contrast the subjective nature of readability.

#### General rewrite

Using the above points the code can be rewritten as

```
const fieldChangeListener = (key,  index = 0, isMulti = false, isAddress = false) => {
  const [field, internalKey] = isAddress ? [key, "addresses"] : ["value", key];
  const isTypeKey = key === "type";
  return event => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    const updated = {...contact};
    if (isMulti) {
      updated[field][index][internalKey] = value;
    } else {
      updated[key] = value;
      const isTypeIndividual = value === "Individual" && isTypeKey;
      if (isTypeIndividual && contact.entityFormationDate) {
        delete updated.entityFormationDate;
      }
    }
    setContact(updated);
  }
}
```

Is it more readable. We that depends on the readers level of experience and skill.

#### Compact rewrite

Personally I would have compacted the code further as its the total quantity (lines of code) that make code navigation the crucial readability factor. Code is seldom read in isolation.

```
const fieldChange = (name,  idx = 0, isMulti = false, isAddress = false) => {
  const [internal, fieldName] = isAddress ? ["addresses", name] : [name, "value"];
  const isType = name === "type";
  return event => {
    const [updated, value] = [{...contact}, event.target.value];
    if (isMulti) {
      updated[fieldName][idx][internal] = value;
    } else {
      const canDelete = (updated[name] = value) === "Individual" && isType;
      canDelete && contact.entityFormationDate && (delete updated.entityFormationDate);
    }
    setContact(updated);
  }
}
```

### Defined readability

Code readability is very dependent on code standards used in projects. Standards must be defined in writing.

This is a document that all project coders should be thoroughly versed in and defines the styles, naming, layout, language features, etc... used and not to use in each project.

It can be argued that a comprehensive code standards document makes it impossible to write unreadable code.

To start a project without a standards document has already failed the first rule of readability. *"Subjectivity is unreliable"*.

Example standards (as un-categorized points) I used for *"Compact rewrite"*

- Fields to have `names` not `keys`.
- `index` is always written `idx`.
- Short circuited end clauses must be grouped.
- Single line expression with multiple assignments must group each assignment.
- Use semicolons.
- Prefer declarations using destructuring assignments over multi-line declarations.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, I read it a few times and feel like I learned a lot from it, thank you!

Comment: Would it be okay to drop the curly brackets from `if (isMulti)`? I know it's possible, but I dont know if there is a standard against it.

Comment: @TomJenkins There is no rule against it but I always delimit all code blocks as forgetting to add the curlies in latter modifications is an very difficult to spot and seemingly random behavioral bug that is 100% avoidable if you always delimit code blocks.